# Why does this SEGFAULT? (small amount of code)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "mystuff.h"

typedef struct Node
{
        int size;
        int status;
        struct Node *next;
        struct Node *previous;
} Node;


Node *endNode;
Node *rootNode;

void *my_foo(int size)
{
        Node *theNode;
        void *ptr;

        if (rootNode->next == NULL)
        {
                theNode->status = 1;
                ...
```

It segfaults at "rootNode-> == NULL" but if I change that to "rootNode == NULL" then it segfaults when it hits "theNode->status = 1" and declaring theNode and rootNode as NULL does not help.

Comment: use $ valgrind ./yourprogram

Comment: I valgrind and it told me 'Use of uninitialised value of size 4', but I don't see where that is exactly

Comment: It seems like you're asking the same question as your other one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892342/making-custom-malloc-what-is-wrong-here), except you seem to have left out a lot of the necessary implementation bits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and declaring theNode and rootNode as `NULL` does not help.

Dereferencing `NULL` (usually) *will* result in a segfault. You've got to set them to something more useful (like an allocated structure) before you go off modifying them!

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. Would you know how I could declare rootNode to be the start of the heap?

Comment: Don't do that. Use `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see rootNode even assignated, residing in the static space it therefore holds the nullptr constant. You are dereferencing it with the -> operator, so it cannot be done.
First make it point to some object !

Comment: thanks you! Would you also know how could I get rootNode to be the beginning of the heap?

Comment: if you are talking of your process heap space, then no, you have no control over that. If you want a large linear region of memory to play inside just do a `char* myheap = new char[virtualHeapSize];` In this case according to your code, you want to do a double linked list. Therefore your first link must be allocated using `rootNode = new rootNode;` Somewhere in a Push() operation controlled by client code. You can code that Push() into the Node struct for example, and call it from the main().

Comment: @v.oddou: `void* myheap = malloc(virtualHeapSize);` would probably work better, considering this is C.  :)

Comment: hadn't noticed the tag :) I don't know about pointer aliasing rules in C but store the heap in a char array is better to ensure the compiler doesn't make idiotic suppositions according to aliasing of that space.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a NULL pointer will result in a segmentation fault.

One can only assume that `rootNode` is NULL, since it will enter the code block when you change the condition to `if(rootNode == NULL)`. One would further assume this is because it was never assigned.

Furthermore, you *clearly* never set `theNode` to point to anything, so the line `theNode->status` will attempt to dereference `theNode`, which points to...who knows what.

Solution: *Assign values to your variables*.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Comment: ok, thanks! So if I wanted to make rootNode the start of my heap would I do something like 
`rootNode = sbrk(0)`?

Comment: Please, don't ever use `sbrk` yourself. Just stick with `malloc`!

Answer (score 0):

Are you allocating memory for rootNode before using fields (I mean rootNode->next operation)?
If not, use malloc before, e.g.:
rootNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)).
Seems that you doing double linked list, may be also a good idea to predefine struct Node *next = NULL;