# making custom Malloc, what is wrong here?

Tags: c, malloc

I've been working on a little custom worstfit Malloc using a double-linked list for a while, and although this is small I thought this would work. Is there anything obvious that is wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "mymal.h"

typedef struct Node 
{
    int size;
    int status;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
} Node;


Node *endNode;
Node *rootNode;

void *worstfit_mall(int size)
{
    Node *theNode = sbrk (size + sizeof(theNode));
    void *ptr;
    if (rootNode == NULL)
    {
        theNode->status = 1;
        theNode->size = size;
        theNode->previous = theNode;
        theNode->next = theNode;
        rootNode = theNode;
        endNode = theNode;
        return theNode;
    }
    Node *worstNode;
    worstNode = worstFit(size);
    if (worstNode != NULL)
    {
        theNode->status = 1;
        theNode->size = size;
        Node *newNode = sbrk((worstNode->size - theNode->size) + sizeof(theNode));
        newNode->status = 0;
        newNode->size = worstNode->size - theNode->size;
        theNode->next = newNode;
        theNode->previous = worstNode->previous;
        newNode->next = worstNode->next;
        return newNode;
    }
    endNode->next = theNode;
    endNode = theNode;
    endNode->status = 1;
    endNode->size = size;
    ptr = sbrk(size + sizeof(theNode));
    return ptr;
}

void my_free(void *ptr)
{
    Node *pointer;
    pointer = (Node*)ptr;
    pointer->status = 0;
    if ((pointer->next->status == 0) && (pointer->previous->status == 0))
        sbrk(-1 * (pointer->next->size + pointer->size));
    else if ((pointer->next->status == 1) && (pointer->previous->status == 0))
        sbrk(-1 * (pointer->previous->size + pointer->size));
    else if ((pointer->next->status == 0) && ( pointer->next->status == 0))
        sbrk(-1 * (pointer->previous->size + pointer->next->size + pointer->size));
    else
        sbrk(-1 * pointer->size);
}

void *worstFit(int size)
{
        Node *theNode = rootNode;
        Node *worstNode;
        while (theNode != NULL)
        {
                if ((worstNode == NULL || theNode->size > worstNode->size) && (theNode->size >= size) && (theNode->status == 0))
                        worstNode = theNode;
                theNode = theNode->next;
        }
        return worstNode;
}
```

Comment: What, precisely, does not work?

Comment: It segfaults IMMEDIATELY with my test driver.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things that immediately strike me:

- `worstFit` does not initialize `worstNode` to `NULL` and tries to read it while it's still garbage.
- You create a linked list of `Node`s, but the tail `Node`'s `next` always points to itself.  Meanwhile `worstFit` expects a `NULL` sentinel value when it iterates over the list.
- `worstfit_mall` does not initialize `endNode` when initially creating `rootNode`.
- `worstfit_mall` returns a pointer to the allocated `Node`, but if it's meant to be substitutable for `malloc`, it should be returning a pointer to memory that the caller is allowed to write to.  You don't want the caller to scribble all over your `Node` data.

  I'd expect `worstfit_mall` to return `((char*) node) + sizeof *node)` (or more simply, `node + 1`) instead of returning `node` directly.  `my_free` would need to do a corresponding, inverse adjustment to retrieve the `Node` pointer.

  `void my_free(void *ptr)
  {
      Node *nodePtr = ptr;
      nodePtr--;
      ...
  }`
- Additionally, it's unclear to me why `worstfit_mall` allocates memory via `sbrk` when going down the `worstNode != NULL` path.  Isn't the point of this path to find an *existing* memory chunk to reuse?  Furthermore, this path calls `sbrk` *twice*.
- Finally, it appears to me that `my_free` unconditionally reduces the amount of allocated memory, but that would work only if you're freeing the last thing you allocated with `sbrk`.  What if you called `worstfit_mall` twice and then called `my_free` on the first result?  There is no path where `my_free` marks the memory chunk as no-longer-in-use so that `worstfit_mall` can reuse it later.

I don't know if there are other problems with your code; I would say that there very likely are given these types of fundamental issues.